# Stored Procedure in mysql Not working

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to insert a value in case not inserted else trying to update some of its field.There is only one variable used.
Value is not inserting although ion calling the store procedure it shows one row inserted.
Kindly help me , trying SP first time.

This is mine stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `InsertLocation`(in IpAddress varchar(45))
BEGIN     
  if (SELECT count(*) as count 
      FROM mbuzzz.location_byhits 
      where IpAddress = IpAddress
      having count>0)    
  then     
      UPDATE location_byhits SET Hits=Hits+1 where  IpAddress=IpAddress;    
  else     
      insert into location_byhits(IpAddress,Date_current) 
      values (IpAddress,CURTIME());     
  End if ;    
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Rename your input parameter** to make it clear to the DB engine when you mean the parameter and when the column name.

```
where IpAddress = IpAddress
```

is always true since the engine thinks you compare a column to itself.

Try

```
delimiter |
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `InsertLocation`(in IpAddrParam varchar(45))
BEGIN     
  if ((SELECT count(*) FROM mbuzzz.location_byhits where IpAddress = IpAddrParam)>0)    
  then     
      UPDATE location_byhits SET Hits=Hits+1 where IpAddress=IpAddrParam;    
  else     
      insert into location_byhits(IpAddress,Date_current) 
      values (IpAddrParam, CURTIME());     
  End if ;    
end
|
delimiter ;
```

Comment: thnx sir ,  makes a lot :)

Comment: Sir, the code is working for new value insertion but not in the case when data exists already.  Hits value doesn't increase ,Is there any possibility

Comment: the hits column is not inserting although there is not duplica'cy but the column value is not updating. In case if require a good change kindly help me out.